# "{" error in remix ide

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, error

Please help. I don't get what the following error means:

> "browser/DGC1.sol:102:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum definition. {contract Doge Coin is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath { ^ "

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `pragma` statement at the beginning of your file. See the [official documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/layout-of-source-files.html#pragmas) for more information.

As an example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

contract Test {
  // Contract logic goes here
}
```